# How to free pointers in array of structs

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

Given the following:

```
struct RES_RECORD
{
unsigned char *name;
unsigned char *rdata;
}
```

Implementing the following within a function/main:

```
struct RES_RECORD answers[20];

for (i=0;i<20;i++)
{
answers[i].name = strdup("Foo");
answers[i].rdata = malloc(SomeRunTimeValue);
}
```

How to I properly free() the memory allocations of the pointers within the array (answers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the way you allocated it:

```
for (i=0;i<20;i++)
{
   free(answers[i].name);
   free(answers[i].rdata);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I was trying free(answers[i]->name) instead!

Comment: ah heheh ... that happens all the time :-)